# ASP.Net MVC View within WebForms Application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am adding functionality to an ASP.Net webforms application and we've decided that new development will be done MVC with a view to move all functionality over eventually.

Obviously, MVC and WebForms play together rather nicely when it comes to accessing an MVC action via a URL. However, I'd like to display the MVC view within an existing tab (telerik) control on a WebForm page. This view will be using js/css file so that will need to be considered also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I'd use jquery/js to load the tab dynamically on page load / select tab. If add a js function to the required handler you can fire an ajaxGet to retrieve the html from your MVC action URL.

If needed I can get some sample code. Are you using jQuery in your ASP.Net app or MSAJAX ??

Cheers
ian